# git merge & rebase: Do they only affect the currently checked out branch?

Tags: git, git-merge, git-rebase

Is it correct to say that the following two commands

```
git merge X
git rebase X
```

**only** change/affect the **current branch** and **not** `X` (or any other branch)?

I think I understand what both commands do, but I want to make sure my assumption is correct.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, your assumption is correct. Both commands will affect only the branch you're on when you run the command.

Comment: Few understand.